# How to display more than 100 event templates?

Tags: civievent

For contact or event search results, the list lenght (number of entries displaying) can be chosen/modified, but not for event templates.

Is there a way to adjust/change the default list lenght for event templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event template field in New/Update Event should display more than 100 options in the drop down, provided they need to be active to be listed.

Comment: You're right, taking this way, templates are manageable. Equal row number features as the ones used for events or contact search results/lists would nevertheless be useful.